# Spring MVC 4 AngularJS 1.3 HTTP POST has null CSRF token or header

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc, spring-security

When I disable CSRF protection then all my POST requests sent by AngularJS are accepted, but when it's enabled I receive the following error:

**ERROR:**

HTTP Status 403 - Invalid CSRF Token 'null' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'.

From what I understood, the request doesn't send any content to match _csrf token or the header isn't set.

I have this in my HTML header code:

```
<head>
  (...)
  <meta name="_csrf" content="${_csrf.token}"/>
  <meta name="_csrf_header" content="${_csrf.headerName}"/>
  (...)
</head>
```

I looked at questions concerning CSRF and Spring that were posted here, but I unfortunately didn't manage to solve my problem although I tried to use various code samples posted as solutions.

I think that I should somehow send the CRSF data with my POST request, but I don't have any idea how to do it.

I'll appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the documentation on angularJS $http and XSRF-token (same thing):

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http scroll down to `Cross Site Request Forgery (XSRF) Protection`

You can configure AngularJs to automatically handle it:

```
The name of the headers can be specified using the xsrfHeaderName and xsrfCookieName properties of either $httpProvider.defaults at config-time, $http.defaults at run-time, or the per-request config object.
```

Comment: Could I ask for code samples as how to do it? The online documentation of AngularJS is somewhat hard for me to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder *why* you want to use CSRF protection in a controller that is written to have a javascript front end. CSRF goal is to avoid that another site will send a redirect post query with unwanted data. If you use AngularJs to get the csrf protected taken, any evil site will be able to send to a browser the javascript code to first get the token and then post the unwanted data. IMHO, you should not rely on CSRF protection when using Ajax.

Comment: @eslaron Looks like I should have read about *same site origin policy* before posting. Unless serious problems in browser, the kind of attack I described is hopefully forbidden. Will delete that stupide post...

Comment: So it would be good to make CSRF work between spring and angularjs, but after all this time I still can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

A quick & dirty solution:

**JSP page**

For simplicity just using jQuery to access the tokens in the meta tags and putting them into JavaScript variables (this might be improved, just did not have time to find out yet, how to read meta tag values directly from AngularJS).

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<head>
    <script src="<c:url value='/resources/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js'/>" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="<c:url value='/resources/js/angular/angular.min.js'/>" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <sec:csrfMetaTags />
    <c:if test="${!empty _csrf.token}">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var csrfParameter = $("meta[name='_csrf_parameter']").attr("content");
            var csrfHeader = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");
            var csrfToken = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
        </script>
    </c:if>
</head>
```

- ensure that the CSRF token are indeed rendered in the page (i.e. that this page is protected by the Spring CSRF filter), i.e. something like the following is contained in the page when you look at the source code (in reality meta tags would be in one line, it just did display correctly in stackoverflow preview when trying to use the original HTML):

> ```
> <meta name="_csrf_parameter" content="_csrf" />
> <meta name="_csrf_header" content="X-CSRF-TOKEN" />
> <meta name="_csrf" content="38452f36-d47b-4d49-b7ec-8b08cb8f9fa8" />
> <script type="text/javascript">
>     var csrfParameter = $("meta[name='_csrf_parameter']").attr("content");
>     var csrfHeader = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");
>     var csrfToken = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
> </script>
> ```

**AngularJS configuration**

Add the following to your app (or module) configuration. Here the JavaScript variables which were implicitly placed into window.csrfToken etc above are accessed using the AngularJS $window service to configure the $http service:

```
app.run(['$http', '$window', '$document', function($http, $window) {
    $http.defaults.headers.post[$window.csrfHeader] = $window.csrfToken;
}]);
```

You may also want to add

```
    $http.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
```

as default header as well.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to change `name="_csrf"` to `name="csrf"`. It seems like underscores aren't allowed in Laravel. This is the case if talking about headers.

For example:

```
$token = Request::header('_csrf'); // Not working

$token = Request::header('csrf'); // Working!
```

*Note that the above applies to Laravel 4.2*